# problem in getting id from query string in.net core in post and put request

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

**when i issue get request i get id of type Guid from query string but when i click on the button or apply
post request i can not get id parameter. why is that and how to solve this problem?**

**this is my server side code.**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromQuery(Name = "id")] Guid id, [FromForm] User user, [FromForm] IFormFile? file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var data = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                        data.Add(await user.ParseToStringContentAsync(), "user");
                        if (file is not null)
                            data.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()), "file", file.FileName);
                        using (var response = await client.PutAsync("UsersAPI/" + id, data))
                        {
                            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                            else ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something went wrong");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await ex.LogAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
            return View(user);
        }
```

**this is my view for the edit action. when i click on the button eveything seems to be working but my id parameter is** *Guid.Empty*

```
@model Models.Model.User

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>User</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @*<label asp-for="User_ID" class="control-label"></label>*@
                <input asp-for="User_ID" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
                @*<span asp-validation-for="User_ID" class="text-danger"></span>*@
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @*<div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="RegistrationDate" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="RegistrationDate" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="RegistrationDate" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Image" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" name="file" class="custom-file" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Image" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean when your query string has `?id=xxxx`,and when you use post or put request,action cannot get the id in query string?Can you show your view code?

Comment: It is because your `asp-action` in your form.

Comment: Hello,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Yo can try to remove `asp-action="Edit"`.When you use it,the request url will be changed to `https://localhost:xxx/xxxController/Edit` here is a working demo:

View:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Edit() {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Edit([FromQuery(Name = "id")]Guid id)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

result:
[image]